# Method returns -1 instead of the number of updated rows

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to do a bulk update in my database by executing a stored procedure. I'm calling the DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand method like so:

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXECUTE TestProcedure");
```

In this crude test, my stored procedure looks like this:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE TestTable
    SET MyColumn = 'changed'
END

Select @@ROWCOUNT
```

When I execute the SProc in SSMS directly, I get the number of rows returned. However, if I do it via the code posted above, I ALWAYS get a result of -1 (even when the SProc executes correctly - which I can verify in my table).

When I change the code to this:

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE TestTable SET MyColumn = "changed");
```

I then get the correct number of updated rows. Since my actual code is more verbose, I'd like to use a SProc, but I need an accurate number of rows affected.

How can I use the SProc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456(v=vs.113).aspx) returns the number of rows affected, not the result of any `SELECT...` statements inside the SQL.

If you want to return the result sets, you will need to use [`Database.SqlQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery%60%601(System.String,System.Object[])) instead.

**EDIT**: As this is Entity Framework Core, the `SqlQuery` method does not exist (yet, it is planned). However, you could do something like this which grabs the raw connection and uses reflection to return the data. It's not particularly efficient but should work:

```
public static class DbContextExtensionss
{
    public static IEnumerable<TEntity> ExecSQL<TEntity>(this DbContext context, string query) where TEntity : new()
    {
        using (var connection = context.Database.GetDbConnection())
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            if(connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }

            using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (result.Read())
                {
                    var entity = new TEntity();
                    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(TEntity).GetProperties())
                    {
                        if (!object.Equals(result[prop.Name], DBNull.Value))
                        {
                            prop.SetValue(entity, result[prop.Name], null);
                        }
                    }
                    yield return entity;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int RowCount { get; set; }
}

var results = _context.ExecSQL<>("EXECUTE TestProcedure");

foreach(var testClass in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(testClass.RowCount);
}
```

**NOTE**: you would need to change the stored procedure to name the column it returns to match the class:

```
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS [RowCount]
```

Comment: @ErikPhilips I was looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx . I incorrectly assumed the line "The result returned by the database after executing the command." would correspond to what what returned by the SProc. I tried to look into this before posting my question. Can you point me to the documentation you're referring to?

Comment: David, this is Entity Framework Core. I don't see a SqlQuery method for the Database class. What package/namespace is it in?

Comment: @MattM DavidG included the link.. it's the first word in his answer.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Just to clarify, I thought by "the documentation clearly states this" you meant this line: "If you want to return the result sets, you will need to use Database.SqlQuery instead."  As I said before, that method doesn't seem to be available in EF Core.

Comment: @MattM Ah apologies for not spotting it's EF Core. Unfortunately you cannot run ad-hoc queries in EF Core - all queries must return valid entites. For example: `_context.Customers.FromSql("SELECT * FROM Customers")`

Comment: @DavidG No worries. Thanks for the answer. I think I'll just need to use a sql string with sql parameters instead of executing a SProc.

Comment: @MattM There's a workaround to get it to work, at least until this feature is embedded in the framework in the future.